# How to dynamically attach attribute to mock-wrapped instance

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I need to be able to attach an attribute to a mock-spy during a test. That is, I want to be able to do this:

```
[ins] In [1]: class Foo:
         ...:     def __init__(self): pass

[ins] In [2]: foo = Foo()

[ins] In [3]: from unittest import mock

[nav] In [4]: mock_foo = mock.Mock(wraps=foo)

[ins] In [5]: mock_foo.a = 1

[ins] In [6]: foo.a  # not assigned to original instance
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b58746ef2d07> in <module>
----> 1 foo.a

AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I tried to overload the `__setattr__` but wasn't sucessful,

Is this possible?

---

why?

I'm trying to change the type of an instance

```
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> mock_foo = mock.Mock(wraps=foo, spec=Bar)
>>> 
>>> if isinstance(mock_foo, Bar):
>>>    mock_foo.fooled_you = 'hah'
>>> 
>>> foo.fooled_you
hah!
```

Comment: Why? What is your end goal that means you need to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloading Mock's `__setattr__` actually does work okay:

```
[ins] In [1]: class MyMock(mock.Mock):
         ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         ...:         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         ...:
         ...:     def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value):
         ...:         setattr(self._mock_wraps, attr_name, attr_value)

[nav] In [2]: foo = Foo()

[nav] In [3]: mock_foo = MyMock(wraps=foo)

[ins] In [4]: mock_foo.y = 4

[ins] In [5]: foo.y
4
```